# Using SMOTE on unbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a 2 class unbalanced dataset where the ratio is 20:1

I am using SMOTE to oversample the minor class and wanted to know when using SMOTE to develop a usable model, if it was best to oversample so that the percentage of the minor class was the same as the other class (i.e 1:1) or establish through trial an error the lowest possible ratio to improve the model overall to an acceptable level (i.e F1Score >0.7) but not use too many synthetic samples if that makes sense.

Any thoughts/advice appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a site for programming questions (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for an overview). Your question would be more appropriate on Cross Validated.

Comment: I see that you have been directed to Cross-Validated but will add a comment hoping it will be useful. There is no clear answer on how to handle imbalanced data. Research papers usually report different number of oversampling using SMOTE (e.g. 100%, 200%, 500%). You could try different settings and select the one that gives the best cross-validation performance. Also for imbalanced data I would suggest using area under the precision-recall curve instead of ROC (see Jesse Davis's paper).

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to undersample the majority class than SMOTING, as in my experience SMOTING never helped.My suggestion would be to try taking all/Most the cases of the minority class and try undersampling the majority class at different ratios to hit a sweetspot in terms of F! Score.
-Thanks
Satish

Answer (score 0):

You can try different SMOTE percentages and nearest neighbors values. Then you chose the best parameters values based on your F1Score for example.

Your best result will not necessary be the one with a highest SMOTE percentage.